# Ionic 7 Angular 15 - this.router.navigate(['home/mypage']) works fine on ionic-serve but not in production

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I have an app where one of the pages redirects the user to a different page after a certain task. The code below works fine when using the development mode and ionic serve.  It redirects the user to mypage.

```
this.router.navigate(['home/mypage']);
```

However, when I do a prod build for a web app and host it on a server, everything else works fine except this.router.navigate.  It gives a 404 error (e.g http://localhost/home/mypage not found).  I have tried it with a slash in front of home too but not success.

I have tried it for different pages and actions but the result is still the same.   I have researched quite a bit today but couldn't find a solution.  Any tips would be great.

I am using Ionic 7 and Angular 15.

Comment: try entering the same url directly on the Address bar and give enter, if it does not work, its a server issue, try checking the server, if the SPA configuration is set properly!

Comment: The URL directly works.  As in SPA configuration, what files should I be looking for?

Comment: Uploaded the app on a live www domain on an Ubuntu Apache2 server.  Still the same issue.  I thought may be because I was running it locally on my mac, it was causing it but seems like some bigger config issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using window.location.reload(); to refresh my list.  Since this is a single page application, it will show white screen.   Instead, I started redirecting the page to a different view so that I don't have to refresh the window.  However, it is disappointing to see that window.location.reload(); worked find in the ionic serve mode but not production.

Answer (score 0):

you can use navigateByUrl without [] as follow :

this.router.navigateByUrl(`/home/${path}`);